# How to set the selectedIndex to -1 when I click a button?

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I would like to see the `SelectedIndex` property of the `dataGrid` when I click a button of the same view. I am trying this code:

```
<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Butn I click the button the `selectedIndex` is not update. I think that the `dataTrigger`, how is set in the style, it is not fired, but really I am not sure.

How can I set the `selectedIndex` property when I click my button?

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your approach and the trigger works fine, you might have messed up the name of your button.

Comment: @Slowbrochacho how can you do that? There is no property `IsPressed` in the Button

Comment: @StepUp, button inherits it from buttonbase, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Slowbrochacho it really works! Thanks for new knowledge!:)

Comment: You can use Click event handler in code behind, really. It's view-related anyway.

Comment: @Slowbrochacho: could you show a code that you are using? What do you mean that it inherits from buttonbase? Thank you so much.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, sure I posted an answer with the harness code I used to check your datatrigger and explained about my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code harness code I used to see that your code works fine. I put comments around your xaml so you can match it up with your own code. The code is just a window with a basic DataGrid, Button and TextBlock bound to the SelectedIndex of your DataGrid. You can see that when you press the button the text of the TextBlock will be set -1, which is what you are setting as the value of your SelectedIndex in your DataTrigger.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IntToStringConverter x:Key="intoStringConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
       <DataGrid Name="dgUsers">
       <!-- Copy and paste of your code -->
           <DataGrid.Style>
               <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
        <!---End of copy paste-->
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="myButton">Reset Index</Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="SelectedIndex: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dgUsers, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource intoStringConverter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
            testList.Add(new Test() { ID = 1, Name = "first" });
            testList.Add(new Test() { ID = 2, Name = "second" });
            testList.Add(new Test() { ID = 3, Name = "third" });

            dgUsers.ItemsSource = testList;
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(string))]
    public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "NULL";
            return value.ToString();
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

In my comment where I said that Button inherits IsPressed from ButtonBase. I meant that you can access the IsPressed property through an instance of a button since a Button is a subclass of ButtonBase which implements [IsPressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`IsPressed` property only have a `get` not a `set` and sometime it can cause problem in triggers.(*like other properties of this type*)however here it is working fine.

**B**ut if you want a different approach try using below:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BadFoldersHistory}" Name="list" Height="200" SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=myButton,Path=Tag}" >

    </DataGrid>

    <Button Content="click" Height="100" Width="200" Name="myButton">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">                
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>                                        
                                        <Int32Animation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag"  To="-1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>                      
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```